# Why right-shifting an address by three bits as a hash function for a fixed-size hash table?

Tags: c, pointers, hash, hashtable

I'm following an article where I've got a hash table with a fixed number of 2048 baskets.
The hash function takes a pointer and the hash table itself, treats the address as a bit-pattern, shifts it right three bits and reduces it modulo the size of the hash table (2048):

(It's written as a macro in this case):

```c
#define hash(p, t) (((unsigned long)(p) >> 3) & \
                    (sizeof(t) / sizeof((t)[0]) - 1))
```

The article, however, doesn't elaborate on why it's right-shifting the address by three bits (and it seems a bit arbitrary at first). My first guess was that the reason is to sort of group pointers with a similar address by cutting off the last three bits but I don't see how this would be useful given that most addresses allocated for one application have similar addresses anyway; take this as an example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    
    int i1 = 0, i2 = 0, i3 = 0;
    
    
    printf("%p\n", &i1);
    printf("%p\n", &i2);
    printf("%p\n", &i3);
    
    printf("%lu\n", ((unsigned long)(&i1) >> 3) & 2047); // Provided that the size of the hash table is 2048.
    printf("%lu\n", ((unsigned long)(&i2) >> 3) & 2047);
    printf("%lu", ((unsigned long)(&i3) >> 3) & 2047);

    return 0;
}
```

Also, I'm wondering why it's choosing 2048 as a fixed size and if this is in relation to the three-bit shift.

For reference, the article is an extract from "C Interfaces and Implementations, Techniques for creating reusable software" by David P. Hanson.

Comment: To make the fixed-size hash table smaller perhaps? (answering the title rethorically).

Comment: But why right-shifting it by exactly _three_ bits?

Comment: Cause you'd wanna keep a good "balance" between memory-consumption (as small as possible) and performance (as fewer collisions as possible)... as always is the case when designing a hash-table solution.

Comment: Oh, wait, that's not it... assuming `sizeof(long) == 8`, first 3 bits are zero on most architectures. So you'd wanna "get rid of them" in order to reduce the number of collisions in your hash table.

Comment: Pointers are kinda random-ish... but they're usually aligned.

Comment: (a) If the author does not explain why, it may be a bad book, and you should regard it with skepticism. (b) Most of the things put into a hash table will be dynamically allocated with `malloc` or related routines—you generally do not need a hash table for things defined a compile-time, although there are times. `malloc` always returns a pointer suitably aligned for any of the basic types in C. So the low bits will be zero. However, if that is the reason, the code would have been better written as `((uintptr_t) (p) / _Alignof(max_align_t) % (sizeof (t) / sizeof *(t)))`.

Comment: every second hash will a duplicate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Memory allocations must be properly aligned. I.e. the hardware may specify that an `int` should be aligned to a 4-byte boundary, or that a `double` should be aligned to 8 bytes. This means that the last two address bits for an `int` must be zero, three bits for the `double`.

Now, C allows you to define complex structures which mix `char`, `int`, `long`, `float`, and `double` fields (and more). And while the compiler can add padding to align the offsets to the fields to the appropriate boundaries, the entire structure must also be properly aligned to the largest alignment that one of its members uses.

**`malloc()` does not know what you are going to do with the memory, so it must return an allocation that's aligned for the worst case**. This alignment is specific to the platform, but it's generally not less than 8-byte alignment. A more typical value today is 16-byte alignment.

So, the hash algorithm simply cuts off the three bits of the address which are virtually always zero, and thus less than worthless for a hash value. This easily reduces the number of hash collisions by a factor of 8. (The fact that it only cuts off 3-bits indicates that the function was written a while ago. Today it should be programmed to cut off four bits.)

Comment: The hash algorithm in the questions cuts 3 bits out of the address, not 3 bytes. And it doesn't just "cut them", in essentially "replaces" them with bits which likely contain "more random" data. In other words, it removes those 3 zero LSBs at the end, and adds 3 random MSBs at the beginning.

Comment: In addition to all of that, your opening statement `Memory allocations must be properly aligned` is not generally correct. It depends on the platform (compiler + HW) in use, and it is most certainly not dictated by the C language standard. It just so happen to be the case on many platforms.

Comment: @goodvibration: What is proper alignment is always implementation dependent. In each conforming C implementation, each object should be properly aligned; your statement that that is not generally correct is incorrect. If a particular C implementation does not require multibyte alignment, then proper alignment in that implementation will be one byte.

Comment: @goodvibration Cutting off 3 bits means rounding down to an 8-byte boundary. And yes, memory allocations must be properly aligned, the C standard mandates that. The C standard also mandates that the result of `malloc()` is suitably aligned for any built-in type. *What "suitably aligned" means, is down to the platform documentation, but the requirement is there in the standard*.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: 1 byte alignment? Seriously??? I didn't realize that theological debates were standard in this website.

Comment: @goodvibration Please, do yourself a favor and do some documentation reading yourself. After you've read the C standard, you may revisit the question whether alignment is a theological debate...

Comment: @goodvibration: Pursuant to C 2018 6.2.8, the alignment requirement for any object is an integer, and, if there are no restrictions on its placement, that integer is necessarily 1. There is no theology; this is just the specification of the C standard.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica *`So, the hash algorithm simply cuts off the three bytes of the address`* wow!! striping 3 bytes of the address. How wide is your address buss 256bits?

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica Also, though this might be due to my misunderstanding, how come you say the alignment is generally not less than 8-byte alignment, typically 16 nowadays? Isn't this contrary to the example in my question and P__J__'s answer where the addresses are clearly _not_ aligned to 8 bytes (but rather 4-byte alignment if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: @j3141592653589793238 Alignment requirements usually take performance into account. So, while a CPU may be able to load a value from any address, it may be significantly slower when it's not aligned to its natural size, or crossing a cache line boundary. As such, alignment requirements tend to follow the size of the largest value that a CPU may load/store to/from memory. A 64 bit architecture has plenty of types that are eight bytes, so you can assume that 8-byte alignment will be required. Vector units contain even larger registers, which typically call for larger alignment, often 16 byte.

Comment: @j3141592653589793238 On top of that is the requirement of allocators to store two pointers within an unallocated chunk of memory. So, if your pointers are 8-byte aligned, the minimum allocatable block size is typically 16 bytes. Most allocators will thus choose (this is not forced, but common practice) to think in terms of 16 byte chunks, always rounding block sizes up at least to a 16 byte boundary, and returning 16 byte aligned blocks. I did write such an allocator once myself. So, 16 byte is both beneficial to vector processing (some CPUs actually require it), and natural for the allocator

Comment: @j3141592653589793238 P__J__'s answer shows the alignment of values on the stack. These may require less alignment than the result of a `malloc()` call: `malloc()` must align for vector processing or an array of `double`, even when you only store a `char` array within the allocation. But the compiler knows how big the individual variables are, what their respective alignment requirements are, and can thus pack them closer. In the example, the variables are `int`, which are 4 byte wide on most platforms, and require no more than 4 byte alignment, so the compiler happily packs them back to back.

Comment: Oooh now that makes a lot of sense, thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 3):

This code assumes that the objects which are going to be hashed are aligned to 8 (more precise to 2^(right_shift) ). Otherwise this hash function (or macro) will return colliding results.

```
#define mylog2(x)  (((x) & 1) ? 0 : ((x) & 2) ? 1 : ((x) & 4) ? 2 : ((x) & 8) ? 3 : ((x) & 16) ? 4 : ((x) & 32) ? 5 : -1)


#define hash(p, t) (((unsigned long)(p) >> mylog2(sizeof(p))) & \
                    (sizeof(t) / sizeof((t)[0]) - 1))

unsigned long h[2048];                    

int main()
{
    
    int i1 = 0, i2 = 0, i3 = 0;
    long l1,l2,l3;
    
    
    printf("sizeof(ix) = %zu\n", sizeof(i1));
    printf("sizeof(lx) = %zu\n", sizeof(l1));
    
    printf("%lu\n", hash(&i1, h)); // Provided that the size of the hash table is 2048.
    printf("%lu\n", hash(&i2, h));
    printf("%lu\n", hash(&i3, h));

    printf("\n%lu\n", hash(&l1, h)); // Provided that the size of the hash table is 2048.
    printf("%lu\n", hash(&l2, h));
    printf("%lu\n", hash(&l3, h));


    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/zq1zfP

to make it more reliable you need to take into the account the size of the object:

```
#define hash1(o, p, t) (((unsigned long)(p) >> mylog2(sizeof(o))) & \
                    (sizeof(t) / sizeof((t)[0]) - 1))
```

Then it will work with any size data https://godbolt.org/z/a7dYj9

Comment: Why would it **fail**? To my understanding, in the worst case it would just yield more collisions, meaning worse runtime performance (than in the case where addresses **are** aligned to 8 bytes).

Comment: @goodvibration it will fail in 50% cases. Not very good function https://godbolt.org/z/xz4cjj

Comment: @P__J__ It still won’t “fail”. It will *collide*. That’s different.

Comment: hash function whis collide in 50% fails and must not be used :).

Comment: I disagree that collision implies failure. It only implies worse runtime performance.

Comment: @P__J__ I have no idea, not my downvote either. I kind of agree that a hash function that collides in 50% of cases could well be considered a failure.

Comment: There is a typo in `hash1`. The version above isn't using `o` (but the one on godbolt is).

Comment: Interesting that the godbolt output for the `hash1` example still has collisions for `&1i` and `&i2`, just like the `hash` example.

Comment: @IanAbbott I do not see the collision there. `hash1` does not have any collisions

Comment: @IanAbbott here you have an easier too see version https://godbolt.org/z/a7dYj9

Comment: @IanAbbott  `p` instead of `o` good spot. Copy paste error

Comment: @P__J__ Sorry, I didn't read the godbolt `hash1` code carefully enough and was assuming the calls were comparing the results for `int`s versus `long`s like the `hash` example, rather than comparing the results for `hash` on `int`s versus `hash1` on `int`s.

Comment: @P__J__ `sizeof(o)` This will work for primitive data types but perhaps one should prefer to use `alignof` if available? Also, out of curiosity, do you think the log2 macro could be simplified/shortened even further?

Comment: @j3141592653589793238 if the `sizeof` is known compile time (ie no variable size arrays) then you can simple use log2 from math.h compilers will remove it if the constant expresiion is power of `2` it will be calculated compile time by any modern compiler I know https://godbolt.org/z/3c7n5M I ahve removed it from my answer knowing that will provoke many pure C standard 200% portability (especially  60y old mainframes)  fanatics

Answer (score 1):

Though it's not dictated by the C language standard, on most platforms (where platform = compiler + designated HW architecture), variable `x` is allocated at an address which is a multiple of (i.e., divisible by) `sizeof(x)`.

This is because many platforms do not support unaligned load/store operations (e.g., writing a 4-byte value to an address which is not aligned to 4 bytes).

Knowing that `sizeof(long)` is at most `8` (again, on most platforms), we can further predict that the last 3 bits on the address of every `long` variable will always be zero.

When designing a hash-table solution, one would typically strive for as fewer collisions as possible.

Here, the hashing solution takes the last 11 bits of every address.

So in order to reduce the number of collisions, we shift-right every address by 3 bits, thus replacing of those 3 "predictable" zeros with something "more random".

Comment: FYI: even if the hardware supports unaligned access, it will always incur a performance cost. Aligned access will always be better. Moreover, some types can use atomic operations on the hardware without a memory lock - but only if aligned (the C++ standard library allows you to test if this is the case for a specific atomic type, though I don't remember how to do it).

Comment: @Myst: HW performance on load/store operations is most certainly out of context for this question, and it has nothing to do with the hash-table solution presented in it (neither with its performance, nor with its correctness).

Comment: You're totally right... but you did write that "_many platforms do not support unaligned load/store operations..._", so I thought I'd post a comment clarifying that ALL platforms have issues with unaligned access - it's just that with some platforms you can pay a performance penalty price instead of having your code fail.

Comment: @Myst: OK, thanks for the informative comment then. I'm not so sure that all platforms indeed "have issues" with unaligned operations (and in any case, you'd need to define "issues" in this context). Some architectures do them "wrongfully" (e.g., write 2 bytes before the destination address and two bytes after the destination address). Some architectures possibly even raise an interrupt. But I believe that at least some of the architectures which do support this type of operations, do so without any penalty (i.e., without having to "split" the operation into two operations).

Comment: The most famous architecture that supports unaligned access in the X86 (ARM also supports unaligned access starting with version 6 or 8, I can't remember)... the penalties I encountered on different systems were **between 8%-36%**, depending on the CPU, the cache and memory address (cache line misses). Unaligned access **always** has a cost. It's just a cost that's harder to calculate. The [facil.io STL `make/test`](https://github.com/facil-io/cstl) will try both aligned and unaligned access. You can see the difference on your system.